# Could we get rid of all unuseful tags? (Tags that alone can't be)

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Lets check this:

http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/query/146225/what-tag-is-most-common-for-first-posts

Well, someone see the problem? I do. The version specific tags and a bunch of overly general tags are overwhelming us. We are not asking ourself:

> Who would filter using it? Who would think this is an expertise area? ([source](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7735/169736))

and are we creating a bunch of tags that most users doesn't have an expertise. The problem with removing tags is... they are way too many! For some reason I found this in a **very** old MetaQ:

> I don't see how user friendliness enters into it. We're not requiring users know the right tags before they submit questions. Community members can and will add and modify tags as appropriate, just as on other SE sites. **The tags aren't for the people asking the question, they're for people answering it**, and for people in the future looking for answers to similar questions. [Nicholas Knight Aug 1 '10 at 2:54](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/34/discouraging-ubuntu-tags#comment113_34)

Which leads me to think, the problem with the tags are that old oaks users don't know or don't care about tags. This will lead to what we've been seeing with the general quality of the site. So the ones in the line of fire:

- [version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/version)
- [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) -> maybe separated in two tags? [Should we split the installation tag into seperate tags for the installation of Ubuntu and the installation of software?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/169736)
- [lenovo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lenovo)
- [toshiba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/toshiba)
- [hp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp)
- [dell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dell)
- [canon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/canon)
- [othermodesl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/othermodesl)
- [othermakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/othermakers)
- [crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/crash)
- [freeze](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/freeze)
- [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/other)
- [another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/another)
- [timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/timeout)
- [localhost](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/localhost)
- [connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/connection) to your hearts?
- [local](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/local) food?
- [remote](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/remote) control?
- [colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/colors) red, blue, yellow?
- [restore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/restore)
- [transparency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/transparency) it depends more in the WM/DM than anything
- [resize](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resize)
- <strike>[grid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/grid)</strike> this tag has been gridded.
- [personalization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/personalization)/[style](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/style)/[customization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/customization) this smells like [theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/theme) so maybe merge? Or retag for the DM/WM/application tag?
- <strike>[view](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/view)</strike> I can view this tag again.
- [preference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/preference) I prefer not having this tag.
- [search](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/search) seems like we answer questions about how to search stuff, instead of what to use for the search.
- [scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) with what?
- [mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mode) /mode hunt-down(crappy & tags)
- I don't want to [copy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/copy) and [paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/paste) the same [text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/text) (note to self: there is a text processing tag).
- [tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tools) to drive me to madness D:
- [upload](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upload)
- I know there are more, but I will get depressed if I continue. Also, seems that one meta Q for each tag could be overkill.

I know that if our mods had [the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/213575) to do this, I would see the world pink... but is grey, stinks and I don't feel comfortable in it. So, can we compile a bunch of tags that everyone is a-OK to feed Trodor?

---

If you feel that a tag is useful, please, make an answer and explain your case but over anything answer this three questions:

- Is there already a equivalent tag?
- Are there users that will follow and answer this tags?
- Could the tag be misused or create a problem later?
- **Is the tag alone in a question useful in any way?**

Comment: How is [tag:installation] useless?

Comment: @ThomasW. what you are going to "install"? How? Using apt? Going to the sources? Ubuntu itself? On some pc? There are too many uses of the tag that nobody's going to follow it since whatever comes could be *whatever*, and tags are supposed to be for the answers find the questions, not the asker describes their question. BTW, SU has the tag but it isn't as general as ours (2.5 k out 200k Q's or 1% vs 11K out 130k or 10%). UL doesn't have it. Correction UL have it in 2 questions.

Comment: @ThomasW. I stand corrected, Gilles just burminated it. They doesn't want it. The use [software-installation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) and [system-installation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) but in our case the later doesn't make sense, since the only thing to install is Ubuntu D:.

Comment: @ThomasW. maybe this idea is of your liking http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/169736

Comment: @Braiam The only thing to install is not Ubuntu, what about software on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Seth [software-installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation)?

Comment: On the other hand there is no "shell" tag and apparently no need for it! http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5486/there-is-no-shell-tag

Comment: @haziz well, look for some questions that really need the [tag:shell] tag, build your case and ask for it to be un-merged.

Comment: I agree on discussing  a tag for theme, something like -appearance-