# Why do you need reputation to use certain tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

Aren't tags used to help people find your question easier if you posted something similar to what their looking for?

If so, then why does this site disallow people from posting certain tags that seem like the perfect tags to add to your question but cannot until you get *_*_ amount of reputation?

For example if I was to put in the word "tags" or reputation in the Tags text box it tells me that It requires 300 reputation for "tags" and 300 reputation for "reputation". Those two words seem like their manditory tags to add for a question like this but why do tags need any reputation at all in order for them to be used?

Actually it seems like anything I try to type in that at all fits with this post requires reputation.

Comment: It tells me that the tag `tag` already exists - so there is not much point to it... see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qU5Eu.png).

Comment: See this is my point exactly this site IMO is extremely to much dependent on reputation to do anything. You need reputation to thumbs up or down, reputation to post certain questions in certain places, reputation to answer other people's questions reputation to add certain tags, etc... Other sites allow you do things similar to what this site can do "for free" without having to use the site's (funny I should use this word) "currency".

Comment: Thanks Captain Obvious. I already know that but how can I post it where it is appropriate when I don't have the "reputation" to post it there? Short answer: I can't.

Answer (score 5):

> See this is my point exactly this site IMO is extremely to much dependent on reputation to do anything. You need reputation to thumbs up or down, reputation to post certain questions in certain places, reputation to answer other people's questions reputation to add certain tags, etc... Other sites allow you do things similar to what this site can do "for free" without having to use the site's (funny I should use this word) "currency".

This is the same reason you don't get the BFG on the first level of DOOM. The restrictions are there for you to learn how the site works before you go off and do maintenance.

(BTW you don't need reputation to answer questions).

Comment: He's probably talking about the 10 rep requirement on protected questions..

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't tags used to help people find your question easier if you posted something similar to what their looking for?

No. Tags are for people capable of answering a question find them fast. The tags are targeted to the people answering. We are [trying to make sense](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7819/169736) of the current state of the tags and creating tags that doesn't have an important amount of already asked question is out of discussion.

> why does this site disallow people from posting certain tags that seem like the perfect tags to add to your question but cannot until you get __ amount of reputation?

This is because the community doesn't trust **you** to know when a tag is useful. For the community trust you, you must build your reputation. You can ask in this meta site for the tag to be created, but unless you demonstrate that the tag has a good user base of answerers is probably that it won't get created.

> if I was to put in the word "tags" or reputation in the Tags text box it tells me that It requires 300 reputation for "tags" and 300 reputation for "reputation".

Those tags are considered meta tags. Because are tags about the site itself, not about any topic contained in the FAQ. Tags and Reputation are inherent to the topics of Ask Ubuntu, hence in the main site shouldn't be created.